# How would I make a dictionary from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How would I go about making a dictionary from a list like this:

```
list = [('a', [10,3]), ('a', [30,20]), ('b', [96,45]), ('b', [4,20])]
```

The result I want is:

```
dict = { 'a':[10,3,30,20], 'b':[96,45,4,20] }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> lst = [('a', [10,3]), ('a', [30,20]), ('b', [96,45]), ('b', [4,20])]
>>> dct = defaultdict(list)
>>> for x, y in lst:
...     dct[x] += y
...
>>> dct
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [10, 3, 30, 20], 'b': [96, 45, 4, 20]})
>>>
```

Or, if you want to avoid the import, try [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
>>> lst = [('a', [10,3]), ('a', [30,20]), ('b', [96,45]), ('b', [4,20])]
>>> dct = {}
>>> for x, y in lst:
...     dct.setdefault(x, []).extend(y)
...
>>> dct
{'a': [10, 3, 30, 20], 'b': [96, 45, 4, 20]}
>>>
```

Comment: Ah, just a bit quicker than me!

Comment: Wow! that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the quick answer too

Comment: Small warning: a `defaultdict` doesn't act completely like a `dict` - so you may wish to `dict()` it before using it after you've done this.

Answer (score 1):

This also works: (it assumes your items are already sorted by key. If not, then just used `sortedi(items)` instead)

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

items = [('a', [10,3]), ('a', [30,20]), ('b', [96,45]), ('b', [4,20])]
d = dict((key, sum((list_ for _key, list_ in group), []))
    # for each group create a key, value tuple. with the value being the
    # concatenation of all the lists in the group. eg. [10, 3] + [30, 20]
    for key, group in groupby(items, itemgetter(0)))
    # group elements in items by the first item in each element
```